# Menus don't work after 4.4

Tags: categories, menus

After I updated to Wordpress 4.4, I noticed that the menu links on the front page of my website don’t work anymore.

The website is:  http://rantaboutfilm.com/
the theme is:  swagger

When the user clicks on any given menu, from anywhere in the site, the website reloads the front page.  However, when the user clicks on an individual article, it brings that up just fine.

- wordpress and theme are both updated to current versions.
- I’ve tried all of the permalink settings.
- new categories (created post update for testing) have the same issue as previously created categories--returns user to homepage.

  It’s been suggested that the problem is with the theme, and that I should change it to Twenty-Fifteen or earlier, to make that determination.  However, I’ve had trouble implementing new themes, namely, in getting pre-existing categories to work in a new theme.  I can create new menus in the new theme, but when I click on them, they’re empty, or show sample content from the theme.  How can I get a new theme to work?

2)  If at all possible, I’d like to keep Swagger.  Is there a way to get it to work again?

3)  If that isn’t possible, is there a theme similar to Swagger?  Is there a theme that’s good for movie reviews?